# Loading multple HTML Pages with different Backgrounds

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to program a TAB based paging.

My problem is each Tab contains a different background, so when I click on the hyperlink, the new background DOES NOT load, BUT the content loads.

Any ideas?

Code here

http://jsfiddle.net/rgarimella/AnBEc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested your jsfiddle, adding !important to your css rules does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/AnBEc/2/

Edit:

Depending on what effect you are looking for you could also remove the .ui-content part of each rule (so that it's just #services) that would apply the background to the whole page and not just the content part: http://jsfiddle.net/AnBEc/3/